# nuxt3 and vuetify load all vuetify components in run dev

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

Situation:
I have an app in Nuxt 3 and use Vuetify3 as a plugin.

Problem:
Every time by `npm run dev` I see a phenomenon that it takes 8-10 seconds to load each side because every vuetify component is loaded.

Question:
Is there a way to accelerate this?
Do i need to limit to vuetify components I use only or maybe some prebuild?

[image: web side load]

/plugins

```
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    ssr: true,
    components,
    directives,
  });

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify);
});
```

and in nuxt.config.ts

```
  css: [
    "vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass",
    "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css",
  ],
  app: {
    baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
  },
  build: {
    transpile: ["vuetify"],
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      API_BASE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    },
  },
  components: true,
});
```

Comment: Does [the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/) answer your question? (e.g: *"Vuetify comes with plugins for both webpack and vite that enable automatic treeshaking."*). Make sure you also read [limitations](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#limitations).

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. Nuxt does not expose webpack or vite. It uses something called nitro, and the problem is not bundle size, but rather that nuxt is doing 700 requests with every page load that all have a considerable lead-up time in dev mode. This question is specifically about bundling those requests so it doesn't spend 28 seconds waiting and 2 seconds sending over data.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't import all components and directives. Let the plugin figure it out instead:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    ssr: true,
  });

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify);
});
```

---

Sometimes you will still import individual components directly, for example when you use them in a render function. Make sure that you are not importing them from `vuetify/components`, but directly from the file, as in `vuetify/components/<component>`:

```
import VBtn from 'vuetify/components' // <---- will load all coponents in dev
import VBtn from 'vuetify/components/VBtn' // <---- will only load VBtn
```

see [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#import-groups)

Comment: I will try the first one, but we are using a lot of vuetify components. Not sure that I will see much of an improvement. It is a large project. It's good to note that in my case things ran well when we were still running the release candidate of vuetify. The second part of the answer is a non-answer. You don't use Nuxt with autodiscoverable components just to manually define every single component that you import anyway.

Comment: Oh, the manual import usually happens when a component is used outside of regular templates, for example in a render function, to extract TS types, to pass it as a prop, etc. It usually doesn't occur more than once or twice - but once is all it takes. I wouldn't dismiss it without checking. Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Need update Node.js version.
For me changing version from 16.19.0 to 18.13.0 reduced page reload time from ~20 sec. to ~1sec.